# SELECT every nth value by Date from large table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

> **Rewrote this question 2012-06-20 for clarity, check edits for older version**

### Background and Question

I collect data for a couple of sensors on some devices. This data I want to display for the user as curves in a graph, i.e. I want to plot the measured points and draw lines between them. The user is able to decide for what date range he wants to show values for by zooming and panning in the graph.

The number of measured values begins to add up and at this moment I have a number of values in the range of *500'000'000*, and counting. For a single sensor I can at most find about *2'000'000* values as of now, but It will most likely increase. These values are not logged at an even interval (i.e. every second) but instead when a change can be measured (see the difference in the date column below).

```
Date  SensorValue
----- -----------
10    123
30    118
70    114
85    115
90    116
95    117
```

Since the display area for this graph is *1000px* there's no point fetching all those values. Instead I try to fetch at most *1000* values and keep them evenly distributed inside the date range the user has zoomed in upon. Exactly which values inside the date range that is returned doesn't matter as long as they are evenly distributed in terms of the date (this is important to remember since they aren't logged at an even interval).

I store these values in a quite simple table as can be seen below, with only one (clustered) index. Notice that the `Date` is stored as an integer ("unix time") not as a `datetime2` field. The table is partitioned by `Date` if that matters.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SensorValues](
  [DeviceId] [int] NOT NULL,
  [SensorId] [int] NOT NULL,
  [SensorValue] [int] NOT NULL,
  [Date] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_SensorValues] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [DeviceId] ASC,
  [SensorId] ASC,
  [Date] DESC
);
```

I'm searching for one of two things, *either* an improved query that will return these values faster, *or* a different approach on how to extract those values. If anything is unclear, keep asking me and I will try to answer.

### My current approach

To achieve this I calculate the difference in time for the date range I'm fetching data for and divides this by the number of values I want to fetch at most. I store this in the variable I call `@resolution` below.

When I query the database it calculates and groups the matching rows by the date divided by `@resolution` and picks out one value per group. I do know that this is not a fool-proof algorithm. In some cases it returns more values than requested, but it doesn't matter that much for me since it at least keeps the number of values down to a manageable level.

For a sensor with small amount of data (tens of thousand of values), this is fairly quick but when it comes to a sensor with much data (millions of rows) it slows down and takes a couple of seconds (at least) to query the database. How should one go about querying for this information in a better way?

```
SELECT sv.SensorValue, sv.Date
  FROM SensorValues sv
  INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(svInner.Date) AS svInner.Date
                FROM SensorValues svInner
                WHERE svInner.SensorId = @sensorid
                  AND svInner.DeviceId = @deviceid
                  AND svInner.Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @stopdate
                  AND svInner.Sensorvalue != -32767
                  AND svInner.SensorValue != -32768
                  GROUP BY svInner.Date / @resolution) j ON sv.Date = j.Date
  WHERE sv.SensorId = @sensorid
    AND sv.DeviceId = @deviceid
    AND sv.SensorValue != -32767
    AND sv.SensorValue != -32768
  ORDER BY sv.Date DESC
```

[image: Query Plan for above query]

**Example:** If I want to select 3 values between time 0 and 95 from the table example above I do the following.

I calculate the `@resolution` to `(95-0)/3=31` and then for each row between time 0 and 95, calculates `Date/@resolution` (integer division everywhere):

```
Date  SensorValue Date/@resolution
----- ----------- ----------------
10    123         0
30    118         0
70    114         2
85    115         2
90    116         2
95    117         3
```

I then select one value from each group by using `MAX(Date)`.

```
Date  SensorValue Date/@resolution
----- ----------- ----------------
30    118         0
90    116         2
95    117         3
```

Comment: is Sensorvalue smallint? What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @gbn: SensorValue is a regular int. SQL Server 2012

Comment: What results do you expect from your sample data, exactly? Why is Date shown as a datetime when the table definition shows it as an int?

Comment: My bad, Date is integer but can be represented (by recalculation) as a string which I displayed for easier interpretion. I've also improved my example.

Answer (score 5):

Technically to display n-th value you use the ranking functions like [`RANK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102), [`DENSE_RANK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)  or [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734). Which one exactly depends, but what you describe matches best `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
with cte as (
 select row_number() over (order by Date) as rn, *
 from table)
where rn % 1000 = 0;
```

But you are saying that you want o do this for performance reasons, avoid going through millions of rows. Such a query had already done the damage, it read from disk all the rows and had to sort them so the performance price was already payed.

A better alternative to selecting a random sample of data is to use the `TABLESAMPLE` clause, see [Limiting Result Sets by Using TABLESAMPLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
select * 
from table tablesample (100 rows);
```

TABLESAMPLE will be way more efficient as it actually avoids reading all the data, it only samples some of the pages in the table and returns all rows in the sampled pages.

But consider that if you use TABLESAMPLE your WHERE clause are applied *after* the sampling. So it may be that the sample does not contain any row for the device/sensor you're interested in. This is specially true for sensor with small data.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think leaving items out of the list by filtering will really change the performance hit. You're still going to scan all the rows. But maybe you can try something like this, which avoids one scan, the self-join and any meaningless aggregation:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT SensorValue, [Date], 
    pn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY [Date]),
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date])
  FROM dbo.SensorValues
  WHERE SensorId = @sensorid
  AND DeviceId = @deviceid
  AND [Date] BETWEEN @startdate AND @stopdate
  AND Sensorvalue NOT IN (-32767,-32768)
)
SELECT SensorValue, [Date]
  FROM x
  WHERE pn = 1
  AND (rn = 1 OR rn % @resolution = 0);
```

Comment: I tried it on my data but it actually performed slower :-(

Comment: @m__ does your table have any indexes?

Comment: my table definition is in the question. I've got a clustered primary key index, nothing else.

Comment: Can you show an actual execution plan for both queries? I suspect an index involving SensorValue might help, but it would be good to understand how many rows we're talking about, cardinality of the clustered index columns, and differences in the two plans. Not sure why this one could possibly be worse.

Comment: I've added the query plans in the question and the answer (next to the actual queries). I also ran `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` on each query and your query executed in _8717ms_ while my original query took _2738ms_, running on the same data set. To add to that is that your query doesn't return the same values as mine does since it looks at the _row number_ instead of the _date_. I don't have the dates evenly spread throughout the data set but I do want my result to be as evenly spread as possible, so this could become an issue for me.

Comment: pn provides a row_number of 1 for each distinct date in your data set. If your solution already runs faster, then keep using your solution. <shrug>

Comment: @AaronBertand, of course I'm going to continue running my own query until I find something more suitable (would've been stupid otherwise). I'm just doing my best to answer your question and helping passers-by to understand my decision not to accept your answer.

Comment: The other problem is that you haven't shown any sample data at all or a single example of what you want returned. So how is anyone supposed to know that their "query doesn't return the same values" as yours? Can you give some clue about what data is in the table, how many rows overall, how many rows are involved when the query starts to get slow, and what results you actually expect?

Comment: I'm not going to get myself into some flame war of who's done the right thing and who hasn't. I thought it was pretty clear from the title what I was trying to achieve _SELECT every nth value **by Date** from large table_ and the table definition was enough to describe my data (but I guess I've learned my lesson this time :-P). I will update the question accordingly, and feel free to ask for more information if needed.

Comment: Flame war? What are you talking about? If you want help beyond what you've received so far, how am I "flaming" you by asking you to provide more information, and explaining why the lack of information has yielded little in terms of helpful answers so far?

Comment: I'm truly sorry, must have interpreted your messages wrongly. I appreciate any help I get and tries to improve my question based on all input I get and will keep doing so (my question is updated with the above information).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm how about something along the lines of adding a new modulo column....

1. make a sensor data key 1, 2, 3 .... N  an ascending unique
   counter up to N your final and last sensor data point.
2. pick R your resolution, as in you want to select every Rth data
   point.
3. for all rows, calculate M = P mod R, and store that value in a
   corresponding M column for all data.
4. Select data where M = x        where x is any number from 0 to R-1

SQL implementation: alter your tables so that the new key P is unique ascending and numeric from 1 to N.  Alter the table so that the you also have a modulo column (integer).

create and execute procedure that fills your modulo column when you want to change the resolution.

```
Create procedure fillModulo
    @R int,  -- resolution parameter
    @N numeric  -- count of number of data points
As 
declare @j numeric = 1;  - our primary counter from one to the last data point

while @j <= @N     --while loop until the last data point
begin
    UPDATE SensorValues
    set modulo = @j%@R
    Where P_Id= @j;

    set @j = @j +1;
end 
go

exec fillModulo @R = 1000, @N = 5000000;
go
```

select your data, picking any number x from 0 to R.  below we choose x = 0 for example.

```
Select * from SensorValues where modulo = 0
```

So the fillModulo procedure you only have to do once every time you want to adjust resolution or add new data (takes a seconds).  But the select would be just a normal select where modulo = 0, which would take no extra time at all.

Alternatively, if you don't intend to change R you can fill the Modulo column automatically during the process that fills the table with data, so it would take a second there, but select is normal time.

Update: Ahh, alternatively see other answer. row_number() is possibly easier to use than altering your table.

Comment: Could've been a solution if it weren't that the resolution changes depending on the user's interactions with my application.

Comment: I see then it may be easier to random sample as Rusanu mentioned.  where sample size is S=  N/R

Comment: you may want to give the user the option to save his loaded random sample in case they don't like static data that looks different each time they refresh view